# Timeout error while attempting to migrate in the ganache-cli

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment, ganache-cli, truffle-config

I'm trying to deploy the smart contract using ganache-cli local blockchain server. I started the ganache-cli server and this is how my truffle-config.js file looks like...

**Truffle-config.js**

```
 module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 9545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    ganache: {
    //  networkCheckTimeout: 1000000,  // gives error: Something went wrong while attempting to connect to the network. Check your network configuration.
      host: "12.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

After compiling -> truffle compile and then migrating -> truffle migrate --reset --network ganache, I'm getting this error...

**Error Info**

```
Error: There was a timeout while attempting to connect to the network.
       Check to see that your provider is valid.
       If you have a slow internet connection, try configuring a longer timeout in your Truffle config. Use the networks[networkName].networkCheckTimeout property to do this.
```

I've cleared my DNS cache as this [post](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/2552#issuecomment-637230636). I restarted the system. Uninstalled ganache-cli then installed it. Nothing workout, Still getting the same error. BTW my internet is not slow.

Anyone, please help. Stuck in this problem for days. I Couldn't find the solution over the internet. So I posted it here.

**Versions**

> Ganache CLI v6.12.2 (ganache-core: 2.13.2) Truffle v5.3.7 (core:
> 5.3.7) Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js) Node v12.21.0 Web3.js v1.3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing development port number to 8545.

```
development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 9545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
```

and put this code to comment try again.It works for me perfectly.

```
 //ganache: {
    //  networkCheckTimeout: 1000000,  // gives error: Something went wrong while attempting to connect to the network. Check your network configuration.
     // host: "12.0.0.1",
    //  port: 8545,
   //   network_id: "*", // Match any network id
  //  }
```